# Factorizing expression with exponents

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I fail to see the justification that allows the textbook author to go from line 2 to line 3.
$$ C_1 e ^{u} - C_1 e^{-u} = 0$$
$$ C_1 (e^{u} - e^{-u}) = 0 $$
 $$C_1 (e^{2u} - 1) = 0$$ 
where $u = \sqrt{-\lambda} L$.

Comment: You're missing a step. $C_1(e^u - e^{-u}) = C_1e^{-u}(e^{2u}-1)$. Now if you set that equal to zero and divide both sides by $e^{-u}$, you'll get line 3.

Comment: @user69810 Thanks. I see it now.. if you post it as an answer I can mark it correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$C_1(e^u - e^{-u}) \\ = C_1e^{-u}(e^{2u}-1) = 0 \\= C_1 (e^{2u} - 1) = 0 \, \\\blacksquare $